# My quadratic equation solver program (Python 3) doesn't give me right solution to the equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

My code is

```
#Import the module
from math import sqrt

#Using while loop statement to make the program not finish before the user close the program.
while True:

#Print out the introduction message, and get the input value to solve the quadratic equation.
    print("ax^2+bx+c=0의 꼴로 된 방정식을 풀 수 있습니다. a, b, c의 값을 차례대로 입력하세요.")
    a = input("a를 입력하세요 : ")
    b = input("b를 입력하세요 : ")
    c = input("c를 입력하세요 : ")

#Define function that checks whether the input values are natural number or negative number
    def func_num(n):
        if n[0] == '-':
            n = -int(n[1:])
            return n
        else:
            n = int(n)
            return n

#Execute the function for the input value a, b, c
    a = func_num(a); b = func_num(b); c = func_num(c);

#This if statement chekcs whether the solution of the quadratic equation going to be real number or imaginary number.
    if b ** 2 > 4*a*c:
        solution1 = ((sqrt((b ** 2)-(4*a*c)))-b) / (2*a)
        solution2 = (-(sqrt((b ** 2)-(4*a*c)))-b) / (2*a)
    else:
        square_root = sqrt( -(b**2 - 4*a*c) ) + 1j
        solution1 = ( (square_root)  - b  ) / (2*a)
        solution2 = ( -(square_root)  - b  ) / (2*a)

#Prints out the solution of the quadratic equation.
    print("정답은 바로바로... {}, {} 이거다!".format(solution1, solution2))
```

and it doesn't give right answer. For some equations, it gives negative value of the solution (solution * -1), sometimes even solution is wrong (not only positive/negative sign), but sometimes it gives right answer.

How can I improve it, and which part of the code occurs the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your formula for the imaginary square root case.  You're *adding* `1j` when you intended to multiply by `1j`.  It should be changed to:

```
square_root = sqrt( -(b**2 - 4*a*c) ) * 1j
                                      ^
```

Another thing to note:  Python is perfectly capable of calculating an imaginary square root -- you just need to use the version of `sqrt` in the `cmath` (complex math) package instead of the `math` package:

```
import cmath
print(cmath.sqrt(4))
print(cmath.sqrt(-4))
```

This way, you can avoid handling the special case for the square root of a negative number.

One final improvement:  it turns out that the `int` function handles strings representing negative numbers just fine (e.g., try `int("-5")` and it works fine), so you can replace your `func_num(a)` function calls with just a call to `int(a)`, etc. (or better yet, `float(a)` which will handle floating point numbers).